# Firebase crashlytics is not catching exceptions

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have followed all the steps and installed the Firebase Crashlytics in my react native successfully. It is capturing the `crashlytics().crash()` but not js exceptions. My firebase.json is as follows:

```
{
    "react-native": {
      "crashlytics_disable_auto_disabler": true,
      "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true
    }
}
```

When i use try-catch block, and log the error using `crashlytics().recordError(error)` it gets recorded but the js errors aren't. How can i do that

**EDIT:** I have tried with release mode and it captures the error but not in the debug mode.